# String naming convention in java

Tags: java, eclipse, string

I am currently trying to make a naming convention. The idea behind this is parsing. 
Lets say I obtain an xml doc. Everything can be used once, but these 2 in the code below can be submitted several times within the xml document. It could be 1, or simply 100. 
This states that ItemNumber and ReceiptType will be grabbed for the first element.

```
ItemNumber1 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("ItemNumber").item(0).getTextContent();
ReceiptType1 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("ReceiptType").item(0).getTextContent();
```

This one states that it will grab the second submission if they were in their twice.

```
ItemNumber2 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("ItemNumber").item(1).getTextContent();
ReceiptType2 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("ReceiptType").item(1).getTextContent();
```

ItemNumber and ReceiptType must both be submitted together. So if there is 30 ItemNumbers, there must be 30 Receipt Types.

However now I would like to set this in an IF statement to create variables. 
I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
int cnt = 2;
if (eElement.getElementsByTagName("ItemNumber").item(cnt).getTextContent();)
**MAKE VARIABLE**
```

Then make a loop which adds one to count to see if their is a third or 4th. Now here comes the tricky part..I need them set to a generated variable. Example if ItemNumber 2 existed, it would set it to

```
String ItemNumber2 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("ItemNumber").item(cnt).getTextContent();
```

I do not wish to make pre-made variable names as I don't want to code a possible 1000 variables if that 1000 were to happen.

KUDOS for anyone who can help or give tips on just small parts of this as in the naming convention etc. Thanks!

Comment: First off, `String ItemNumber2 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("ItemNumber").item(cnt).getTextContent();` looks like your combining JavaScript with Java. Anyhow, this looks like a case for Arrays. `var ItemNumbers; ItemNumbers[1] = ...; ItemNumbers[2] = ...`

Comment: Do keep in mind the standard Java naming conventions:  Leading upper-case for class/interface names, leading lower-case for variable and method names, all caps for constants.

Comment: You should look into JAXB for this. Your real problem seems to be deserializing, not naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't know beforehand how many ItemNumbers and ReceiptTypes you'll get ? Maybe consider using two Lists (`java.util.List`). Here is an example.

```
boolean finished = ... ; // true if there is no more item to process 

        List<String> listItemNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> listReceiptTypes = new ArrayList<>();

        int cnt = 0;

        while(!finished) {
            String itemNumber = eElement.getElementsByTagName("ItemNumber").item(cnt).getTextContent();
            String receiptType = eElement.getElementsByTagName("ReceiptType").item(cnt).getTextContent();

            listItemNumbers.add(itemNumber);
            listReceiptTypes.add(receiptType);

            ++cnt;

            // update 'finished' (to test if there are remaining itemNumbers to process)
        }

        // use them :

        int indexYouNeed = 32; // for example

        String itemNumber = listItemNumbers.get(indexYouNeed); // index start from 0
        String receiptType = listReceiptTypes.get(indexYouNeed);
```

Comment: how should I check to see if there is another item to determine what to set the Boolean? Ill +1 you and set answer if you can help me finish this :). Thanks.